# Some program is showing ads on my desktop... How can I catch it?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-3, ads

Some program keeps showing me ads on the main page every now and then. It's extremely annoying, and I'm unable to catch it. Is there a way I can detect it to remove it?

When the ad shows up, I try to hold the home button to see the app name, but it disappears. Sometimes the ad is a link, so it asks me for the browser to use. My device is rooted.

Comment: check `Settings >  Apps > Running` and look for 3rd party apps that you installed. One of them is responsible.

Comment: @BharatG Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that already actually. There are many... Trying one by one will take a very long time as an ad is shown every 15-20 minutes.

Comment: you can try to disable some apps from starting at boot to check. like autostart manager. i don't know allowed here or not but the bigtincan may be useful too.

Comment: @lftekharAS I will do that once I know what app is doing that!

Comment: Look thorough your third party apps. Think about what apps might be a bit suspicious. Adware is usually hidden in apps not made by large corporations.

Comment: See if my answer helps you: [Find what app is causing popups, NOT in notification bar](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/119306)

Comment: @EthanZ I couldn't find anything suspicious, that's why I'm posting the question... I removed half of my apps and still... :(

Comment: @Firelord I installed AdAway... let's see if that helps! :)

Comment: @Firelord problem solved! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Finding the Source

**For Android >4.1**

If your device is running Android 4.1 "Jelly Bean" or higher, you can just press and hold on notifications and your device will tell you who is generating them.

**For Android <4.1**

Use [Airpush Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brosmike.airpushdetector&hl=en). This application has a big list of apps that create banner ads. If it finds an application it knows of, it will tell you and ask you to uninstall.

---

### Stopping the Future Problems

Use an Adblocker to Block Ads:

1. [AdFree](http://adfree.odiousapps.com/) *(Recommended)*
2. [AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/android-install)
3. [Ad Away](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway)

Answer (score 1):

I installed [AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/android-install) (not the browser, click on the gray link in below the big link in the middle) and [AdAway](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway) and this solved the problem. Unfortunately this works only if your device is rooted.

Comment: Good to hear that the problem solved, but isn't adaway alone enough for you? Why are you using two ad blockers?

Comment: What grey link are you talking about? did you not think maybe they might change their website design?

Comment: @barlop It's dead now. I now use DNS666 from Aptoide store.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist thanks. I  used  Airpush detector which was mentioned in Matt's answer. It found two culprit apps.  I'll try DNS666 too.

Answer (score 0):

You can install AdwCleaner! With it you can remove Adware,PUP/LPI (Potentially Undesirable Program), Toolbars! I have used it, and its very good! It does a great job!

Then you can use adblock plus, to prevent any other ads from showing up! But first use adwcleaner!