# How to remove or disable pop-up alert()/confirm() box from build-in Browser from malware?

Tags: browser, malware

My young niece install low rating free games from Store and she have no any security concern.

Some malicious application open malicious site which ask for money in `alert()` and `confirm()` message boxes.

Because of dumb way how official Browser works it is not possible disable or remove infinitely pop-up boxes or close malicious tabs.

How can I close this tabs?

I only think about factory reset but that method too radical.

Comment: Uninstall those malicious apps using any applicable method (`adb`, Package Manager or even through recovery by deleting files).

Comment: I have uninstalled malicious apps via Market  app. But I can't recover Browser - in order to close tabs I asked to answer to `alert/confirm` message box. On click OK it open message box again and again... I just need to close all tabs - but message boxes block all phone area and steal focus.

Comment: Delete all data and cache of the browser. This should bring you right back to your homepage.

Comment: Where is cache/data on file system for build-in Browser app? I have access to device via `adb`.

Comment: Are you able to access *Settings*? It's easier that way, just hit the *Delete data* button and all data+cache is removed. It may be scattered around the phone's storage, depending on how the manufacturer build the default stock browser

Comment: I enter to *Settings*, locate *Browser* application and hit the *Delete data* button. Problem solved. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

1. First step would be to remove those apps as also suggested by @Giant Tree
2. These kind of apps are invariably bundled with ads. You can install software recommended here [Some program is showing ads on my desktop... How can I catch it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126326/some-program-is-showing-ads-on-my-desktop-how-can-i-catch-it). You don't need to install all, any one is enough (I presume your device is NOT rooted, Adaway requires root)

3.That should hopefully solve your issues related to adware. Adware is different than Malware. If some malware has entered your system,it fools the system and lodges itself deep into your device like a system app. Factory reset will NOT help and only way out is to flash stock ROM again. This article would help you identify malware http://securitywatch.pcmag.com/mobile-security/309980-five-signs-your-android-device-is-infected-with-malware

Answer (score 1):

[GiantTree](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/86358/gianttree) gave right suggestion for my case:

> Delete all data and cache of the browser. This should bring you right back to your homepage
>
> Are you able to access Settings? It's easier that way, just hit the Delete data button and all data+cache is removed. It may be scattered around the phone's storage, depending on how the manufacturer build the default stock browser.

So I enter to *Settings*, locate *Browser* under *Application* ==> *All* and hit the *Delete data* button. Problem solved.