# format and install new OS to get rid of viruses

Tags: installation, operating-system, antivirus, formatting

I have an android phone (my uncle's) that is full of viruses that display adds and reinstall themselves I'm guessing
there is no important/needed data on the phone

I tried factory reset, after used Dr Web to find viruses, and to root the phone (Kingo ROOT) in order to be able to remove some of them, 2 files identified by drweb couldn't be removed even though the phone was rooted because they were system files (priv-app/baseservice.apk and another one), I renamed them instead.

all this ^ didn't helped completely, they appear again somehow, so would like to format and clean install a new OS

**is there a easy way to do that ?**
my guess is I need some program on my pc (windows7) for this and connect the phone using usb and run some commands

the device is a fake galaxy S6, Android 5.0.2 kernel version 3.10.61

Comment: **`fake`**  `galaxy S6` That is probably the problem.

Comment: what does "fake" mean in this context?  pirated ROM?  branded but built in some shadowy factory?

Comment: @thufir it was a s6 lookalike,  but with much lesser hardware, and root apps malware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, some background

- **Anti Virus**. Android devices are not susceptible to viruses as Windows machines are. To understand more see this [Is an antivirus really needed for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/341/is-an-antivirus-really-needed-for-android). So, installing anti virus is not helping any, unless it scans for malware also
- **Malware**. Malware in Android devices works by losing itself into `/system` ,i.e., behaving as if it is a system app. Factory Reset does not change anything in `/system` partition, so it does not help. You could try installing apps suggested here to check for malware [Some program is showing ads on my desktop... How can I catch it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126326/some-program-is-showing-ads-on-my-desktop-how-can-i-catch-it). You could read this for tell-tale [symtoms of malware](http://securitywatch.pcmag.com/mobile-security/309980-five-signs-your-android-device-is-infected-with-malware)

Second, if you have a malware that can't be removed, only thing to do is to flash a new OS or stock OS a you rightly thought. This is going to be a challenge as getting **reliable** OS may be a challenge and you would need to search in various ROM forums of you can locate one that works on your device.You would find flashing instructions provided with ROM.

**Important Note**

Any ROM that works on Samsung S6 (Original) won't work on your device and may cause your device to be bricked. Be sure to flash a ROM meant for your device. Please read these to understand

- [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35925/can-i-install-a-rom-made-for-a-different-device):
- [Feasibility of flashing a ROM (meant for original device) on a re-branded device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128536/feasibility-of-flashing-a-rom-meant-for-original-device-on-a-re-branded-device)

Is it tough to flash a new ROM? Not really, if you take your time in understanding the instructions IMO, finding a ROM from a reliable source is the biggest challenge. My search (not very thorough) didn't lead me to any source

Comment: Are you sure about `Factory Reset does not change anything in /system partition`? I always thought it resets the system partition to what it was before, but you might be right

Comment: Absolutely sure. That is how malware becomes a nuisance . You can read on factory reset tag here to understand more

Comment: FACTORY reset only deletes user installed apps and data. Hence it is often confused with re flashing original ROM. Factory reset didn't flash original ROM again

Answer (score 2):

Things you can do:

1. Downgrade to your stock ROM and **install a good antivirus** and run a complete device scan because some of them are powerful enough to remove viruses from system files in priveledged user mode.
2. **Install Ubuntu Touch instead of android as shown in [this guide](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/linux/how-install-ubuntu-touch-image-3531970/)**. The guide is actually primarily for nexus devices but you can make it work for Galaxy S6 by finding the stock ROM yourself and other stuff for the S6 yourself instead of following the links given in the guide which are for nexus devices.
3. If that doesn't work and you are unable to install Ubuntu touch for some reason try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Installing_on_a_mobile_device).

Comment: thnx, I actually did the first step and it helped a bit, but the viruses keep coming back, I installed top 3 antiviruses and rooted the device, so the antivirus could remove them, but it didn't help completely

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the phone by rooting it and uninstalling a bunch of system apps (anything that felt suspicious, google helped) ,
apparently the phone had malware apps preinstalled (root apps),

I also removed the sms app by accident, but it's ok, the owner doesn't use sms