# AD's will popup on screen

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat

Each time when i turn on my WiFi, ads will popup and apps will get installed automatically. Some times WiFi switch's on automatically and junk apps gets downloaded.

Comment: Related: [Find what app is causing popups, NOT in notification bar](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63140/16575) // [Some program is showing ads on my desktop… How can I catch it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/126326/16575) // our [malware tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/malware/info) // [questions mentioning popups, tagged `malware` and having answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[malware]+popup+answers%3A1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear you have some sort of malware. I'd consider one of three options:

1. Antivirus - May get rid of the virus without harming your legit files.
2. Fresh reinstall of the stock ROM - WILL get rid of any viruses...along with anything else you had on your phone. It WILL NOT fix any malware-esque behaviours that were built into the rom
3. Install a custom ROM - Like 2), will get rid of any viruses and the popular custom ROMs, for example Cyanogenmod, do not have any malware-esque behaviours. This option requires you to root your device and unlock the bootloader. Googling 'install cyanogenmod ' should tell you what you need to know.

I would try the solutions in that order to save on unnecessary lost data or technical ordeals.